# datepicker icon vanish after update date or add date

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker

I have  a web page that when a user enter a date this automatically saved in database. Also I have a datepicker icon to select the date. But when I update or  i press a add button to add a new entry(or delete icon in order to delete a specific entry) all datepickers icon vanish. I refresh the page in order to datepicker icon appears again. I think that ajax call ignores javascript date picker
    HTML code:

```
echo "<td class='main'><input disabled id='".$row['a_id']."' class='apousies_edit datepicker' tabindex='$tabindex_counter'  onclick='update_record(event,this,&quot;apousies&quot;,&quot;$key&quot;,&quot;id&quot;,&quot;".$row['a_id']."&quot;)' value='$val'></td>";
                    $tabindex_counter++;

    echo "<button class='button4' onclick='new_record_adeia(&quot;$id&quot;);showDatePicker(tabindex)' value='Προσθήκη Άδειας'/><img src='add.png' width='40' height='40'></button>";
```

Ajax call:

```
    function new_record_adeia(id) {

        loadXMLDoc("/prosopiko/add_rec_adeia.php?id="+encodeURIComponent(id),function()
                {
                      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

                        document.getElementById('apousies_edit').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


                })


    }
```

The code that i use in order to add a date:

```
    session_start();
        include "classes.php";
        $functions=new classes;

        $id_proswpiko=trim($_REQUEST["id"]);
        $now=date('Y-m-d');
        $res=$functions->query("INSERT INTO apousies(id_proswpiko,id_logos,start_date,diarkeia,id_status_adeia) VALUES ('$id_proswpiko',1,'$now','4','1')");

        $functions->create_apousies_screen($id_proswpiko);

Jacascript code to show the datepicker I get it from this:
https://github.com/chrishulbert/datepicker/blob/master/datepicker.js
```

Update a date:

```
session_start();
include "classes.php";

$functions= new classes;

$table=trim($_REQUEST["table"]);
$field=trim($_REQUEST["field"]);
$val=trim($_REQUEST["val"]);
$check_field=trim($_REQUEST["check_field"]);
$check_var=trim($_REQUEST["check_var"]);    

$sql="UPDATE $table SET $field='$val' WHERE $check_field='$check_var'";

$result=$functions->query($sql);
```

What is going wrong and my datepicker dont work?

Answer (score 0):

> datepicker icon vanish after update date or add date

The icon vanish because the datepicker library setups the date pickers when the form loads (specifically when the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires). Then, you make an ajax call that replaces the HTML, that includes the date picker icons, with an updated list of items.

Since at that point the library already did its job, the new html controls won't get the datepicker icon (neither any functionality related to that library).

IMHO you have two alternatives:

- Modify the library, in order to add an `setupPicker` method that you can manually call after replacing the HTML with the ajax result.
- Use a different library, that already provides that functionality.

I'd go for the second option, since that library is 9yo, and the `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` (see the source code at the end) looks very bad for performance.

Comment: Thank you Roimer about your instant answer

Comment: Someone else has a different opinion?